# Use Selenium to execute on a manually opened browser window

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am converting a IE HTML web scraping script to selenium for the impending death of IE.

I am struggling to find a comparable piece of code that I have been using for COM controls for IE within the selenium library that will allow me to execute a script on an manually opened browser window - Which in my use case has no work around due to the way the browser is opened.

Effectively, I run a program that opens a browsers on my behalf and requests a 2FA from my mobile, after which having been rendered allows me to navigate around the web application.

I have tried this with selenium opening and a sufficient wait time to enter in the 2FA, however it is immediately met with access denied due to bot detection.
I have explored a range of addarguments to counter this with no avail, including:

```
.AddArgument "--no-sandbox"
.AddArgument "--headless"
.AddArgument "--disable-plugins-discovery"
.AddArgument "--disable-extensions"
.AddArgument "--disable-infobars"
```

I have also tried adding manual useragents with no success, which has led me to believe that the only way i'll get around this if is Selenium can control the browser that is launched without any of the webdriver items.

I'd love some assistance on this.

Comment: This is not a supported feature.

Comment: That wont work. You might have luck with kamelo. I know they have a method on hijacking a browser once launched. Or you could try puppeteer but I have no clue honestly..

Comment: A while back I read something about copying your whole chrome profile to the selenium controlled browser. Didn't do it back then, but it might be worth a try? As it will have cookies and other 'human' behavior in it.

Comment: AFAIK Selenium is not intended to grab a non selenium launched browser for security reasons.